# Drop "draggable" into Handsontable cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, handsontable

I'm tiring to use  Handsontable jQuery module with jQuery UI drag&drop functionality, but without success. I've fount some code with insertAtCaret function, but I have troubles using it with Handsontable.
I want to be able, to drag element from outside of Handsontable table, and drop it into cell. I know, that I have to update cell somehow...
Please help...

**CODE:**

```
$.fn.insertAtCaret = function (myValue) {
    return this.each(function(){
        //IE support
        if (document.selection) {
            this.focus();
            sel = document.selection.createRange();
            sel.text = myValue;
            this.focus();
        }
        //MOZILLA / NETSCAPE support
        else if (this.selectionStart || this.selectionStart == '0') {
            var startPos = this.selectionStart;
            var endPos = this.selectionEnd;
            var scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
            this.value = this.value.substring(0, startPos)+ myValue+ this.value.substring(endPos,this.value.length);
            this.focus();
            this.selectionStart = startPos + myValue.length;
            this.selectionEnd = startPos + myValue.length;
            this.scrollTop = scrollTop;
        } else {
            this.value += myValue;
            this.focus();
        }
    });
};
```

[**My JSFiddle with source**](http://jsfiddle.net/yWP2Z/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `insertAtCaret` code is not really what you need for this situation. You've already got a good handle on the required transaction - you need to use the `ui.draggable` element in the `drop` event to manually add some text to the correct cell. You just need a few final steps.

Now, one key piece of information is that Handsontable wants you to set cell data *by coordinate*, which means you need to know the column and row of the thing you want to set, *not* just have a javascript reference to the actual dom element. For that, we can use [jQuery's index method](http://api.jquery.com/index/).

1. Find out what cell the draggable has been dropped on.
2. Determine what that cell's column and row are.
3. Use Handsontable's `setDataAtCell` method to change the data.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yWP2Z/1/)

```
$("#excel_table").droppable({
    ...
    drop: function(event, ui) {

        // Get a reference to the handsontable instance
        var ht = $('#excel_table').handsontable('getInstance');

        // Hide the helper, so that we can use .elementFromPoint
        // to grab the item beneath the cursor by coordinate
        ui.helper.hide();
        var $destination = $(document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY));

        // Grab the parent tr, then the parent tbody so that we
        // can use their index to find the row and column of the
        // destination object
        var $tr = $destination.closest('tr');
        var $tbody = $tr.closest('tbody');

        var col = $tr.children().index($destination);
        var row = $tbody.children().index($tr);

        // Use the setDataAtCell method, which takes a row and
        // col number, to adjust the data                           
        ht.setDataAtCell(row, col, ui.draggable.text());
    },
    ...
});
```